# (When) do students typically learn about limit superior and inferior?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, education, limsup-and-liminf

I've been taking the [Khan AP Calculus BC](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc) course, and I also have been following through with [pretty extensive calculus notes found here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/).  In neither of these (or when I learned Calc in high school) did they discuss limit inferior and superior, and yet I've seen it come up quite a few times on MSE and on Wiki.

Is this a High School vs College Calc distinction?  The latter link is pretty rigorous (lots of proofs) and is for college.

Is it more covered in Analysis courses rather than Calculus?  What is the typical pedagogy around this?

Comment: I believe questions like yours are better suited to the [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) SE site. However, please check their [Help center](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help) first before possibly posting to make sure your question is appropriate for the site, as well as determine how to best write it for that site.

Comment: I can speak from personal experience; I hadn't learnt limsup/liminf concepts formally in high school, but encountered them in a college real analysis course, which formalized many of the ideas taught in high school calculus.

Comment: In the UK I think it is standard that this is first covered in first year undergraduate (of a maths degree)...

Comment: for me, it was a Thursday

Comment: I am a fourth year applied mathematics undergrad, and I only learned about limsup and liminf last semester.

Comment: In my experience, $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$ are encountered lightly in a standard real analysis course, since the meat of work is done with a limit which we know exists. One encounters them first more seriously in measure theory, since continuity is not assumed and the always-existence of the $\inf$ and $\sup$ gains new importance. For example, consider how essential Fatou's Lemma is.